# Deploy PyICU in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, icu, transliteration

I am trying to use PyICU library inside a AWS Lambda function written in python and using 3.12, but I can't seem to do it.

So far i've tried to locally install with pip in the deployment package that I then upload to AWS, but that will not do the trick.

I've also tried to install it with pip but inside of a docker using the `amazonlinux` image, then dragging the libraries installed to the deployment package, but that will not do either.

Am I missing some step in between?